# Auto hide menu after click on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, menu, navbar

In mobile view menu don't hide after click on link. How can I set this?

I try to add some jQuery but it doesn't work.

Comment: 1. Add all relevant code to OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you please put below js.

```
if (jQuery(window).width() < 960) {
    jQuery('.navbar-collapse a').click(function (e) {  
        if( jQuery(e.target).is('a') && jQuery(e.target).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle' ) {
            jQuery('.navbar-collapse').collapse('toggle');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the menu still does not retract

Comment: It was a mistake with function closing character. Now it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: I observed problem on desktop. After aplly this function on desktop after click menu it plays like animation with scrollbar. Can anything be done about it? Maybe I can set jquery with some @media queries to do only on mobile view?

Comment: @Pat I have updated my answer would you please check it?